# Cannot inherit from final class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I installed Android studio 0.4.2 at Windows 7(64-bit). Try create simple project from studio, but I get an error:

> Cannot inherit from final class

- I try both **studio64.exe** and **studio.exe**.
- I try both jdk 1.7 u45 x86 and jdk 1.7 u51 x64
- gradle 1.9 from repo.

In my virtual machine XPx32 with all this files a-studio work perfectly (I just copy android-studio,

**c:\Users\%user%.AndroidStudioPreview**, **c:\Users\%user%.gradle** from my real vachine into virtual).

I'm behind a proxy with ntlm.

log is:

```
2014-01-19 12:31:20,504 [  22420]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - Cannot inherit from final class 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Cannot inherit from final class
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:185)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:113)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:61)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:41)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl$1.produce(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:49)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:48)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:137)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:123)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:471)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4$2.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:549)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:436)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:153)
```

**UPDATED**

In my project 3 subprojects.
Top-level build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Main project build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':wheel')
    compile project(':appRater')
    compile files('libs/android-support-v13.jar')
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')
}
```

In all subprojects build.gradle are:

```
apply plugin: 'android-library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Comment: include you build.gradle file in question.

Comment: Add build.gradle files

Comment: looks fine . check my answer if it can help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems a bug in android studio not specific but related to

```
Cannot inherit from final Class
```

Try comment #9 in below reported bug if it solves yours problem as well.

**BROKEN LINK NOW**

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63953

**#comment9 was**

Close Android Studio, take a backup and delete all these files from your studio setup directory and start it again, might be it can help you

```
android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-0.6.1.jar
android-studio/plugins/android/lib/builder-model-0.6.1.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-base-services-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-build-setup-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-core-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-messaging-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-native-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-plugins-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-tooling-api-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/gradle-wrapper-1.8.jar
android-studio/plugins/gradle/lib/guava-11.0.2.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the above answer and before deleting the files, i opened the project which is broken, Android Studio told me gradle is out dated, and there was a small URL in the message that says fix gradle... this did something, but did not quite solve my problem. Afterwards, i deleted the files above, and everything worked.