# Android Studio new project ExternalSystemException

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I just make new project, by [File] - [New Project]. I set to min-sdk : 2.3, target : 4.0.3. I didn't change any option(except location, app name..), but I cannot built the project.

On the bottom of Android Studio, "ExternelSystemException" is printed. My android studio version is 0.4.3, and here is the whole error message.

```
Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not create an instance of Tooling API implementation using the specified Gradle distribution 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip'.
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:185)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.invokeGradleTasks(GradleTasksExecutor.java:326)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.invoker.GradleTasksExecutor.run(GradleTasksExecutor.java:189)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$TaskRunnable.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:464)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$8.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:373)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$8.run(ApplicationImpl.java:420)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:150)
```

I think that there must be a problem with gradle. But it's my first time to try to use Gradle, I don't know what is the better solution. Should I re-install Android Studio? or gradle 1.10 is the problem, so downgrade it?(actually I don't know how)

Thank you for read my question.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21441204/gradle-error-in-android-studio-0-4-3

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the link of the comment, and tried many solutions.

After that I realized that the easiest way is 'just reinstall Android Studio'. Make sure that delete .gradle and .android folder before reinstall.

Upgrading Android Studio makes many problems. Just re-install it.