# Error:Cannot inherit from final class. Android Studio

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio, gradle

Not able to work with Android Studio. I get an error **Gradle project refresh failed**.

I use Android Studio 2.1.3, JRE 1.6.0_65, OS X El Capitan 10.11.5.
Here's a screenshot of the error:

[image]

I have tried all other solutions based on other posts. But it didn't help me solve the problem. Ready to provide required or additional info.

**Edit** : I had to reinstall OSX to solve this. My superficial guess could be that the .jar files jam up the system and Android Studio gets confused to load required files.

Comment: Tried [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213487/cannot-inherit-from-final-class)?

Comment: @Shaishav I have tried that. There aren't any such files in the directory to delete other than _builder-model-2.1.0-alpha6.jar_. Still doesn't work.